# How do I allow htaccess authentication via cookie?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've read a lot of different articles about how to check for a cookie and authenticate using htaccess, but for the life of me I can't get it to work on my apache server. After several hours of trying, I decided to ask. I figure this has to be a simple answer, but I have as of yet figured it out.

I wanted the user to enter there credentials using basic auth, if fail then proceed to a custom php page that would then authenticate and set a temporary cookie. Managed to do that successfully. The issue is that I can't get htaccess to read the cookie and authenticate the user.

My .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 401 /authorization.php

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted"

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*login.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://google.com/$1 [L]

AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd
<RequireAny>
     Require user User1 User2
</RequireAny>
```

For example's sake, the cookie has a name of "login" and data of "loggedin". And is set in php with the setcookie() function. In this example it does prompt the user for username and password and it does go to authorization.php when it fails. I have confirmed that the browser does have the cookie and expiration is set far in advance.
.

Comment: Can you show us your `setcookie` function?

Comment: Can you tell us the value of the directive `AllowOverride` on your Apache VHost?

Comment: @Lithilion setcookie in php is initiated with: setcookie("login", "loggedin", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

Comment: @Ayake973 I checked and AllowOverride is set to "AllowOverride All" in my VHost file.